# Saving file to Sharepoint folder from Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I am trying to save a file (.jpg, .pdf, etc.) from my local drive into the SharePoint document library using VBA in Excel. I have the following code:

```
Dim SharepointAddress As String
Dim LocalAddress As String
Dim objNet As Object
Dim FS As Object

SharepointAddress = "\\companyname.sharepoint.com\sites\Team\Shared Documents\img\"
LocalAddress = "C:\folder\exp.jpg"
Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If FS.FileExists(LocalAddress) Then
FS.CopyFile LocalAddress, SharepointAddress
End If
Set objNet = Nothing
Set FS = Nothing
```

With this, I get the impression Excel is trying to connect, but just get a path error. I believe the issue is either I have the wrong path I need for the SP library, or the method I am using is completely wrong. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you browse (in Windows Explorer) to the `SharepointAddress` path you've specifed?

Comment: @CLR No. I reformatted the address to this from what I read online.

Comment: That is the problem then. You need to find the Windows Explorer address to the folder you're using. If you open the site in **Internet Explorer** (not Chrome or Edge) you have the option to open the folder in Windows Explorer. Use that, and you'll see the full address.

Comment: @CLR Thanks again. I tried both in IE and in Edge in IE mode. In both cases it says that MS Office 365 applications are no longer supported in IE (or Edge when opened in IE mode). So I can't access the site from either browser.

Comment: You can't browse in I.E. to `\\companyname.sharepoint.com\sites\Team` ? (replace with your address etc.)

Comment: @CLR, No, simply browsing to office.com is not supported by either IE or Edge in IE mode.

Comment: If you're unable to browse to the sharepoint folder (not office.com) then it's likely a permission thing and any VBA run by a user will use their credentials - and thus also not be able to connect. Perhaps speak to your IT dept or whoever runs your sharepoint site about it.